# How convert list of dictionaries into dataframe with certain criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a list of dictionaries:

```
list_dict = 
[{0: 0.1, 1: 0.2, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.4, 'Product': 'A'}, 
{0: 0.5, 1: 0.6, 2: 0.7, 3: 0.8, 4: 0.9, 'Product': 'B'}, 
{0: 1.1, 1: 1.2, 'Product': 'C'}]
```

I would like to make it into dataframe like,

```
|State    | Probability   |Product|
|---------|---------------|-------|
|0        |0.1            |A      |
|1        |0.2            |A      |
|2        |0.3            |A      |
|3        |0.4            |A      |
|0        |0.5            |B      |
|1        |0.6            |B      |
|2        |0.7            |B      |
|3        |0.8            |B      |
|4        |0.9            |B      |
|0        |1.1            |C      |
|1        |1.2            |C      |
```

Can anyone help me with how to do that? I tried `pd.DataFrame(list_dict)` but the output is different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the dataframe

```
> pd.DataFrame(list_dict)

0    1    2    3 Product    4
0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4       A  NaN
1  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8       B  0.9
2  1.1  1.2  NaN  NaN       C  NaN
```

You can combine the columns and remove the incomplete rows with `melt`, which turns the wide columns [1,2,3,4] into a long column "Probability"

Followed by `dropna` to remove the incomplete/unspecified rows

```
> pd.melt(pd.DataFrame(list_dict), id_vars=["Product"], var_name="State", value_name="Probability").dropna()

   Product State  Probability
0        A     0          0.1
1        B     0          0.5
2        C     0          1.1
3        A     1          0.2
4        B     1          0.6
5        C     1          1.2
6        A     2          0.3
7        B     2          0.7
9        A     3          0.4
10       B     3          0.8
13       B     4          0.9
```

Comment: Alternative: `df.set_index('Product').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'State',0:'Probability'})` using `stack`. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.groupby` followed by `.apply(unstack)`, but it'll take a bit of cleanup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_dict)
df = df.groupby('Product').apply(pd.DataFrame.unstack).reset_index().drop(columns='level_2')
df = df.replace('Product', np.nan).dropna().rename(columns={'level_1': 'State', 0: 'Probability'})
```